# How to show symbols above and below the summation (\sum) symbol using markdown for Github-Pages?

Tags: github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

How do I show symbols above and below the summation sign [image: symbol]
using `<img src="https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?{}>` ? Is it possible? If not, what are my other options to render such a math symbol?

I closest I got is `<img src="https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?math={\color{black} \sum_{d=0}^{d_{max}}}">` which give [image].  But this layout is not what I desire to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that `https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?` is using latex commands. Hence, the command `\displaystyle` needs to precede `\sum` to achieve the format that I desire.

Therefore `<img src="https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?math={\color{black} \displaystyle\sum_{d=0}^{d_{max}}}">` gives [image].